# How load xml data from another domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, sencha-touch

I need load some xml data from service in another domain. If i use ajax request i get "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.". 
I tried use Store with scriptag proxy and xml reader, but i get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
v

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
        model: 'myModel',
        proxy: {
            type: 'scripttag',
            url : url,
            reader: {
                type: 'xml',
                root: 'users'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });
```

Question: how load xml data from another domain using sencha or other javascript library.

Comment: Do you have control of the backend that sends the XML ? if not you cant do it ...

Comment: If you have control over the domain/server the html is served from, you may be able to set up a proxy on that web server.

Comment: scripttag only works with json reader

Answer (score 1):

1) In case you have access to backend you can enable cross-origing resource sharing(CORS):
[how to do it](http://enable-cors.org/). It will allow you to get xml data from another domain.

2) If not you can use YQL(but it looks like dirty hack) : [here](http://christianheilmann.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/)

3) Anyway when you will run your application on mobile device this problem should go away.

4) If you want to find  solution to test your application on desktop browser I suggest you to use chrome. Because there is a way to disable this security restriction:

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

5) And the last tip is to find JSON services because JSONP requests don't have such problem.